# Adding JPanel to JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing

I have added buttons and **text fields** to a panel, but when I try to add the panel to the `MenuItem` nothing happens. I have defined an `ActionListener` for the `MenuItem` in which I am adding the `JPanel`. No error is detected by the compiler, but nothing happens when I click the `MenuItem`. How can I resolve this issue?

```
public class MenuFrame extends JFrame {
    private JMenu customers;
    private JMenu purchase;
    private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

    public MenuFrame() {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        panel1.add(button);
        customers = new JMenu("Customers");

        JMenuItem createInvoice = new JMenuItem("Create");
        JMenuItem updateInvoice = new JMenuItem("Update");
        JMenuItem deleteInvoice = new JMenuItem("Delete");

        sales.add(createInvoice);
        PanelHandler p = new PanelHandler(panel1);
        createInvoice.addActionListener(p);
    }

    private class PanelHandler implements ActionListener {
        private JPanel panel;

        public PanelHandler(JPanel p) {
            this.panel = p;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // getContentPane().removeAll();
            // getContentPane().setVisible(true);
            // JButton b=new JButton("Enter");
            // panel.add(b);
            panel.setVisible(true);
            add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            getContentPane().doLayout();
            // update(getGraphics());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i have but it also contains some other coding

Comment: Then strip it down and add a simple example of your problem.

Comment: import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.MenuKeyListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.Color;
/**
 * Created by user on 1/12/2015.
 */
public class MenuFrame extends JFrame {

Comment: If you are trying to add code, add it to your question.

Comment: i have stripped many please now u can tell me

Comment: I tried to clean your code up, it is still hard to tell. Is `sales` a `JMenu`? Also, you can remove [your comment above. (click to see)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004190/adding-jpanel-to-jmenuitem#comment44397156_28004190)

Comment: You seem to be adding the panel directly to the JFrame instead of its ContentPane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't invoke doLayout() directly.

When add (or remove) components from a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.realidate();  // to invoke the layout manager
panel.repaint(); to repaint components
```